# Uncompressing a .zip file in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I have a .zip file (it contains multiple files, e.g., `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt`) in a directory.

How can I extract the files from the zip archive into the very same directory? And how can I create the list of all the files extracted from the zip archive?

The extracted file name should be printed like this in the file named: file_list:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
filen.txt
```

I have tried the following command assuming that my .zip file name is "data.zip".

```
unzip -qoj data.zip | unzip -ql data.zip  > file_list
```

I have used `unzip -qoj data.zip` to extract all the files in the same directory (quietly, overwrite, junk_path). When I try to insert `-l` with the first unzip command, the command doesn't extract the file in the current directory, and only files are listed. That's why I have to use unzip again after the first pipe. (If I am making a mistake here, please let me know.)

I get the following output:

```
 Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  12-21-09 14:25   data/
     6148  12-21-09 14:25   data/.DS_Store
        0  12-21-09 14:25   __MACOSX/
        0  12-21-09 14:25   __MACOSX/data/
       82  12-21-09 14:25   __MACOSX/data/._.DS_Store
       82  12-11-09 13:59   data/file1.txt
      120  12-11-09 13:59   data/file2.txt
      166  12-11-09 13:59   data/file3.txt
 --------                   -------
     6598                   8 files
```

How do I extract only `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file3.txt` from this stdout?

Is it possible to do this with a Linux command, or do I have to write a perl script for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
unzip data.zip data/file1.txt data/file2.txt data/file3.txt
```

Comment: what if I have 100 files in .zip archive?

Comment: unzip -l data.zip|gawk '$NF~/^data\/file.\.txt$/{print $NF;}'|xargs unzip -qoj